# Async / Await on created method - Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have `vue-element-loading` package, added it's component in my page.vue:

```
<vue-element-loading :active="isActive" :is-full-screen="true"/>
```

Added variable to data:

```
data () {
  return {
    isActive: false,
  }
}
```

Then triggering `isActive` to `true` when the page finishes load:

```
async created () {
  this.isActive = true
  await this.fetchData()
  this.isActive = false
}
```

`fetchData` is an axios get request with response. Idea is to show loader, till axios properly fires and getting response. But now, my loader shows for 0.1 milliseconds, then disappears.

Here's the `fetchData` method:

```
fetchData () {
  axios.get(globalConfig.OFFERS_URL)
    .then((resp) => {
      this.offersData = resp.data
      console.log(resp)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
},
```

Comment: Is axios just returning cached results? That would be very quick.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, i've added my method, does it cache at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your `fetchData()` doesn't return the `Promise` from the call to `axios.get()`, so `await`ing it would resolve immediately (i.e., before the `axios.get()` completes).

The fix is to return the result of `axios.get()`:

```
fetchData() {
  return axios.get()
           .then(/*...*/)
           .catch(/*...*/);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. Any downfalls using `return` in my case? `Promise` it's `.then`, right? By return promise everyone meant to exactly use `return` statement?

Comment: I mean, i still don't get concept of Promises in js, could you explain in simple words?

Comment: Please see [`Promise` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).